# How to constantly change IP to avoid getting blacklisted by website for crawling?

Tags: bash, ip

I am trying to crawl a lyrics website and have made pretty good script (although slow running since this is my first time)

```
#!/bin/bash

touch visited
touch tobe

>visited
>tobe

url=$(echo http://www.azlyrics.com/)
UA=$(echo "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A")

wget -q $url --user-agent=$(echo UA) -O index.html
cat index.html | grep \"http.*.html\" -o | cut -f2 -d\" >> temp_tobe

for i in `cat temp_tobe`;
do
    basename $(echo $i) >> tobe
done

rm temp_tobe

while true;
do
for i in `cat tobe`;
do
    echo getting $url -> $i
    wget -q $url$i --user-agent=$(echo UA)
    echo $i >> visited

    #PUT THE NEW LINK TO TOBE
    cat $(basename $(echo $url$i)) | grep \".*.html\" -o | cut -f2 -d\" >> tobe

    #SORT VISITED
    cat visited | sort | uniq > tmp && mv tmp visited

    #SORT TOBE
    cat tobe | sort | uniq > tmp && mv tmp tobe

    #REMOVE THE INTERSECTION FROM TOBE
    comm -23 tobe visited > tmp && mv tmp tobe

done
done
```

But i think i have been blacklisted to do this since i am not able to access that site even from the browser. I starte my VPN but still not able access the site (THIS IS INSANE!!!) saying `The connection was reset` everytime

I have heard of a technique in which you constantly change your IP (piggybacking behind other users online)

Can you enlighten me as to how to achieve this (Preferably  THIS)
OR Any other method to still access the website

Please ask for clarification if needed

Comment: pls care to give the reason for -1

Comment: I've not downvoted (at this point) but I imagine it's because you're asking how to bypass a measure someone has put in place to protect their system from your actions. It's like asking how to get over the gate someone's erected to stop you walking across their property - one answer is "stop walking on their property".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest one way to do that, maybe it's not the best but it will do the job.
Use tool for `tor` called `torify` or `torsocks` in you script before `wget`:

```
torify wget -q $url --user-agent=$(echo UA) -O index.html
```

this command will let the request go throw tor server, but, first of all you have to download `tor` server then lunch it, after that fill free to do what you want with `torify`:

To install it, for example on CentOS or Ubunutu:

```
yum install tor
apt-get install tor
```

by default `torify` will be installed.

Comment: wouldn't using tor make the crawler extremely slow?

Comment: @juggernaut1996 it will make it slow, but not extremely

Comment: `1481981770 PERROR torsocks[27145]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)` how do i solve this

Comment: did you start `tor` service ?

Comment: how do i keep telling tor after few iteration to change the circuit and get a new ip now??

Comment: you can do it in the configuration file in `/etc/tor/torrc`, better to google it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50224/discussion-between-juggernaut1996-and-wissam-al-roujoulah).